# How to have WinForms RichTextBox render with same line spacing in .NET and .netcore?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-core

I have a .NET Framework WinForms application that uses the standard RichTextBox to view/edit some RTF files.
I've ported the application to .NET Core.

As you can see in the images, the displayed text have different line space heights. I've found that this is due to the hyperlink in the RTF file. If I remove it then their display is same.
[image: Different display of RichTextBox in .NET and .net core]

Can anyone explain why the display is different in the two applications and is there anything I can do to make their display same?

A sample application demonstrating this can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8otx6fe9s4cl77d/AAA1I--TqSrEbVqCHacNj-g8a?dl=0), along with a [sample RTF file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lbk3jmim08u2fzs/Document.rtf?dl=0).

Comment: The RTF contains two `/par` instructions, one empty at the end of each paragraph. Plus a lot of RTF tags that the RichTextBox (50W) does not handle. Remove the empty `/par`. .Net Framework 4.5.2 uses the `RICHEDIT20W` (RichEdit class) Control, .Net Framework 4.7.2+, .Net Core 3.1 and .Net 5 all use the `RICHEDIT50W` (MSFTEdit class) version. Hence, some difference in behavior is expected. -- You could also try to force the `RICHEDIT60W` version (in the `CreateParams` override of a Custom Control).